# 7zip not allowing file extension in the archive name

Tags: command-line, archiving, 7-zip

```
7za.exe a C:\temp\file.txt.7z C:\temp\file.txt
Error:
there is no such archive
```

why is 7zip not allowing file extension in the archive name?
I even tried it with simple period in the archive name, and it is not allowing me

1. `file.txt.original` when zipped should be `file.txt.original.7z`
2. `file.txt.20150220` when zipped should be `file.txt.20150220.7z`
3. `file.txt_20150230` when zipped should be `file.txt_20150230.7z`

It is not allowing me to zip such files from a command line calling `7za.exe`

What do I need to do here? Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is wrong. To create a 7zip file from txt files you would do:

```
C:\Users\Sam>7za a -t7z files.7z *.txt
```

The command you wrote would be looking for an existing compressed file called file.txt.7z and add file.txt to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "for" loop and a wildcard

```
for %f in (file.txt*) do 7za.exe a %f.7z %f
```

See below: note different version of 7 zip It is still the same.

```
C:\temp>for %f in (file.txt*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %f.7z %f

C:\temp>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a file.txt.20150220.7z file.txt.20150220


7-Zip 17.00 beta (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2017 Igor Pavlov : 2017-04-29

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 0 bytes

Creating archive: file.txt.20150220.7z

Add new data to archive: 1 file, 0 bytes


Files read from disk: 0
Archive size: 106 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok

C:\temp>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a file.txt.original.7z file.txt.original


7-Zip 17.00 beta (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2017 Igor Pavlov : 2017-04-29

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 0 bytes

Creating archive: file.txt.original.7z

Add new data to archive: 1 file, 0 bytes


Files read from disk: 0
Archive size: 106 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok

C:\temp>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a file.txt_20150230.7z file.txt_20150230


7-Zip 17.00 beta (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2017 Igor Pavlov : 2017-04-29

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 0 bytes

Creating archive: file.txt_20150230.7z

Add new data to archive: 1 file, 0 bytes


Files read from disk: 0
Archive size: 106 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok
```